# Публикация на 4pda apk файла приложения с целью его продвижения

Tags: android, продвижение

Здравствуйте! У меня такой вопрос. Я написал приложение под Android и хотел бы его опубликовать. Слышал, что хорошим способом бесплатного продвижения приложения считается публикация его на 4pda. Я никогда не был завсегдатаем этого сайта, поэтому может чего упустил из виду. Но когда погуглил на эту тему, то увидел только платную услугу продвижения приложения с написанием обзоров на него за 8-16 тысяч рублей. Я не особо верю в коммерческую успешность своего приложения (вообще рассматриваю его как пробу пера и пункт в портфолио и резюме) и поэтому не хочу тратить на него деньги, которые оно явно не отобьет. В общем вопрос: может кто знает или у кого был опыт, как продвигать там свое приложение бесплатно? Где и как его там публиковать и вообще насколько это может быть полезно в плане продвижения? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Для начала можно просто создать там тему и время от времени постить что-то новое.

Comment: А вот с модерами там лучше не связыватся, 4pda всегда не любили за то что там у каждого модера ЧСВ как у трёх богов.

Comment: Был проект - удался. Закончился. Теперь платно.

Comment: Автор порта Half-Life на Android опубликовал там своё творение, а его взяли и удалили без объяснения причин, а потом тему пересоздали какие-то левые люди, так что я бы советовал не связываться, раз там такие сволочи

Comment: (*там - это на форуме 4pda, забыл уточнить)

Answer (score 3):

На 4pda раньше можно было бесплатно опубликовать статью в рамках программы поддержки наших разработчиков. Сейчас этой услуги нет, только платно можно.

Я тогда свою игру публиковал, какой-то рост закачек статья принесла. Платно там не вижу смысла публиковаться.

Создайте лучше тему в разделе игр и выложите свой .apk

Answer (score 2):

Создаете тему на форуме, оформляет ее согласно шаблону и правилам. Как вы и сказали, платная только услуга рекламы, обзора на главной странице.